# Move GameObject over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity from a Swift SpriteKit background where moving a sprite's x Position is as straight forward as an running an action as below:

```
let moveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width/5, duration: 1.0)
let delayAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
let handSequence = SKAction.sequence([delayAction, moveLeft])
sprite.runAction(handSequence)
```

I would like to know an equivalent or similar way of moving a sprite to a specific position for a specific duration (say, a second) with a delay that doesn't have to be called in the update function.

Comment: I highly recommend using an extension like iTween for this kind of controlled animations

Comment: @caulitomaz Does not need iTween or plugin for that.He simply need to learn Coroutune.

Comment: do not use iTween here, forget that.

Comment: Hi @Nullititiousness.  What you fundamentally have to get with is that Unity is a game engine, hence: **is a frame based system**.  Everything is about frames.  (Note indeed that in iOS, since it's not fundamentally frame based, they screw about and do things "frame-like" to compensate for the fact that it's just not a frame-based system, but sometimes you need things "like that".)  In any event, if you say "I want to 'move' something".  What are you **actually saying**?  You're saying you want to do something every frame - right?  If you start thinking that way it's easy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

gjttt1's answer is close but is missing important functions and the use of `WaitForSeconds()` for moving **GameObject** is unacceptable. You should use combination of `Lerp`, `Coroutine` and `Time.deltaTime`. You must understand these stuff to be able to do animation from Script in Unity.

```
public GameObject objectectA;
public GameObject objectectB;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(moveToX(objectectA.transform, objectectB.transform.position, 1.0f));
}


bool isMoving = false;

IEnumerator moveToX(Transform fromPosition, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{
    //Make sure there is only one instance of this function running
    if (isMoving)
    {
        yield break; ///exit if this is still running
    }
    isMoving = true;

    float counter = 0;

    //Get the current position of the object to be moved
    Vector3 startPos = fromPosition.position;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        fromPosition.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }

    isMoving = false;
}
```

Similar Question: [SKAction.scaleXTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37389374/3785314)

Comment: Thanks! Can `Vector3.Lerp` also be used on a `rotation`, imagine if you want to also have the object rotate from `startRotation` to `endRotation` (x,y,z)

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes. You can use `Vector3.Lerp` to change the `transform.eulerAngles` if it is an incremental rotation. If you just want to go from rotationA to rotationB then `Quaternion.Lerp` should be used to change `transform.rotation`. The rest of the code remains the-same. See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37588536/3785314) answer for that solution.

Comment: It's not so much that Unity threads are sheit as that Unity has to support 20 different platforms with some reasonable guarantees about behavior. In that light, they've done a great job IMO.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of git1 is good but there is another solution if you do not want to use couritines.

You can use `InvokeRepeating` to repeatedly trigger a function.

```
float duration; //duration of movement
float durationTime; //this will be the value used to check if Time.time passed the current duration set

void Start()
{
    StartMovement();
}

void StartMovement()
{
    InvokeRepeating("MovementFunction", Time.deltaTime, Time.deltaTime); //Time.deltaTime is the time passed between two frames
    durationTime = Time.time + duration; //This is how long the invoke will repeat
}

void MovementFunction()
{
    if(durationTime > Time.time)
    {
        //Movement
    } 
    else 
    {
        CancelInvoke("MovementFunction"); //Stop the invoking of this function
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's true that this works perfectly well, and everyone should learn to use InvokeRepeating.  Normally, it's idiomatic to use a coroutine here.

Comment: Note that `Time.deltaTime` is the time passed since the last frame was rendered => This value might be inaccurate during the first frame (when `Start` is called)

Answer (score 1):

You can use co-routines to do this. To do this, create a function that returns type `IEnumerator` and include a loop to do what you want:

```
private IEnumerator foo()
{
    while(yourCondition) //for example check if two seconds has passed
    {
        //move the player on a per frame basis.
        yeild return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it by using `StartCoroutine(foo())`

This calls the function every frame **but** it picks up where it left off last time. So in this example it stops at `yield return null` on one frame and then starts again on the next: thus it repeats the code in the `while` loop every frame.

If you want to pause for a certain amount of time then you can use `yield return WaitForSeconds(3)` to wait for 3 seconds. You can also `yield return` other co-routines! This means the current routine will pause and run a second coroutine and then pick up again once the second co-routine has finished.

I recommend checking the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) as they do a far superior job of explaining this than I could here