# how to translate a sprite for a certain duration using C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Generally I know how to translate a sprite to a given position, but how can I translate a sprite to a given position over a time period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked [over](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36851965/3785314) and over again. Simply searching on Google would have came up with an answer on SO.

This can be done with the use of `Lerp`, `Coroutine` and `Time.deltaTime`. The example below will move the Object from postion A to B within 1 second. You should pass in the current Object's position to the **first** parameter and the new position to move to, in the **second** parameter.The **third** parameter is how long(in seconds) it will take to move the Object.

```
public GameObject objectectA;
public GameObject objectectB;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(moveToPos(objectectA.transform, objectectB.transform.position, 1.0f));
}


bool isMoving = false;

IEnumerator moveToPos(Transform fromPosition, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{
    //Make sure there is only one instance of this function running
    if (isMoving)
    {
        yield break; ///exit if this is still running
    }
    isMoving = true;

    float counter = 0;

    //Get the current position of the object to be moved
    Vector3 startPos = fromPosition.position;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        fromPosition.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }

    isMoving = false;
}
```