# Rotate GameObject over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I a new here and i try to start working with Unity Engine.

Could somebody explain me, how works Quaternion.Slerp? Because I want to rotate some object in different angles 90, 180 and 270. My code you can see below. Unfortunately when I add 180 degrees, object make crazy things and than put rotation to (0, 180, 180) for this game object. I would like to get (180,0,0)

```
    public float speed = 0.1F;
    private float rotation_x;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            rotation_x = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
            rotation_x += 180;
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(rotation_x, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z), Time.time * speed);

    }
```

Comment: Never use quaternions ***for any reason***.  What you are trying to do is ridiculously simple.  ***All you have to do is call transform.Rotate.***  It's just that easy.  Likely something like this ... transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

Comment: I tried to use "transform.Rotate". Unfortunately I have no idea how I can interpolate this rotation to get smooth move. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most examples out there including Unity examples from their official website are using Lerp in the wrong way. They didn't even bother to describe how it works in the API documentation. They just starch it in the `Update()` function and call it a day.

`Mathf.Lerp`, `Vector3.Lerp`, and `Quaternion.Slerp` work by changing from one position/rotation to another with the **t** value(last parameter) being passed in.That **t** value is also know as time.

The min of the **t** value is **0f** and the max is **1f**.

I will explain this with `Mathf.Lerp` to make it easier to understand. The `Lerp` functions are all the-same for both `Mathf.Lerp`, `Vector` and `Quaternion`.

Remember that `Lerp` takes two values and returns values between them. If we have a value of **1** and **10** and we do Lerp on them:

```
 float x = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 10f, 0f); will return 1.
 float x = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 10f, 0.5f); will return 5.5
 float x = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 10f, 1f);  will return 10
```

As you can see, the `t(0)` returns the **min** of the number passed in, `t(1)` returns the **max** value passed in and `t(0.5)` will return **mid** point between the **min** and the **max** value. You are doing it wrong when you pass any **t** value that is `< 0` or `> 1`. That code in you `Update()` function is doing just that. `Time.time` will increase every second and will be `> 1` in a second, so you have problems with that.

It recommended to use `Lerp` in another function/Coroutine instead of the Updated function.

**Note**:

Using `Lerp` has a bad side of it when it comes to rotation. `Lerp` does not know how to rotate Object with the shortest path. So bear that in mind. For example, you have an Object with `0,0,90` position. Lets say you want to move the rotation from that to `0,0,120` `Lerp` can sometimes rotate left instead of right to reach that new position which means it take longer to reach that distance.

Let's say we want to make the rotation `(0,0,90)` from whatever the current rotation is. The code below will change the rotation to `0,0,90` in 3 seconds.

**ROTATION OVER TIME**:

```
void Start()
{
    Quaternion rotation2 = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 90));
    StartCoroutine(rotateObject(objectToRotate, rotation2, 3f));
}

bool rotating = false;
public GameObject objectToRotate;
IEnumerator rotateObject(GameObject gameObjectToMove, Quaternion newRot, float duration)
{
    if (rotating)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    rotating = true;

    Quaternion currentRot = gameObjectToMove.transform.rotation;

    float counter = 0;
    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        gameObjectToMove.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRot, newRot, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
    rotating = false;
}
```

**INCREMENTAL ANGULAR ROTATION OVER TIME:**

And to just rotate the Object to 90 in z axis, the code below is a great example of that. Please understand there is a difference between moving Object to new rotational point and just rotating it.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(rotateObject(objectToRotate, new Vector3(0, 0, 90), 3f));
}

bool rotating = false;
public GameObject objectToRotate;

IEnumerator rotateObject(GameObject gameObjectToMove, Vector3 eulerAngles, float duration)
{
    if (rotating)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    rotating = true;

    Vector3 newRot = gameObjectToMove.transform.eulerAngles + eulerAngles;

    Vector3 currentRot = gameObjectToMove.transform.eulerAngles;

    float counter = 0;
    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        gameObjectToMove.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(currentRot, newRot, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
    rotating = false;
}
```

All my examples are based on frame-rate of the device. You can use real-time by replacing `Time.deltaTime` with `Time.delta` but more calculation is required.

Comment: I'd really be glad if you could help me out on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066807/issues-rotating-an-arbitrary-point-around-another-arbitrary-point

Comment: @TenOutOfTen Not on my Unity computer now. When I'am in  front of it, I will take a look at the question if it has not been answered yet

Comment: Okay, it has been answered but the answer is not in the direction of what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Before anything, you can't add 180 on euler angles like that, and that's mainly what is causing your problem. You'd better use quaternion directly instead, or work on the transform itself.

You can think of a quaternion as an orientation in space. In contrary to what have been said, I do recommend learning how to use them if you can. However, I don't recommend using euler angles at all... as they're suject to different writing conventions, and will fail sometimes. You can look at 'gimbal lock' if you want details about that.

Simply a slerp or lerp (standing for spherical linear interpolation, or linear interpolation respectively) is a way to interpolate (go from one orientation to another, by increasing t from 0 to 1, in a coroutine or anywhere else) between orientation A and B. The difference between the two is that the slerp is giving you the shortest path from A to B.

In the end, when t = 1, lerp(A,B,t) and slerp(A,B,t) will give you B.

In your case, if you want to instantly rotate an object in space to a specific orientation, I suggest you use Quaternion.AngleAxis which is the most forward way to describe mathematically a quaternion.

If you want to add a rotation, say 90° to you actual orientation (without animation between the two), you can do something like this :

transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(axis_of_rotation, angle)
or use transform.rotate (depending on the parameters, it can be a right multiply, or left : local, or world transform).

Programmers' answer is detailling how to animate your transform. But I do suggest you to investigate quaternion themselves, as it will give you global understanding of space transforms.