# Slowly rotating towards angle in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, virtual-reality

I am using SteamVR and would like to rotate the camera based on the height that a controller has been raised, I have written the script that sends the the height of the controller through to a method on my camera script.

When I do the following, the rotation works:

`transform.Rotate(0, 0, 30); // 30 is just to test, we will use the controller height later`

But I would like to do this rotation slowly, this must not happen immediately.

I have also tried using Quaternion.Lerp, but it does not seem to be working.

`Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, new Quaternion(this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, zPosition, 0), Time.deltaTime * 5);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which function do you have this in?

Comment: This is being called from the update of my Controller script, if the height is greater than my threshold, I call this function to rotate to a increment of the height.

Comment: You want to rotate incrementally, 90 degrees, in the Z axis?

Comment: Yes, as if I were turning my head sideways. 

`transform.Rotate(0, 0, 30);` rotates it correctly, but the below rotates is as if I were looking directly right.

`Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 0, 30);
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(direction);
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 2);`

Comment: Can you try the `RotateObject` function from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41651803/3785314) answer?

Comment: @Programmer, see my answer posted below. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: Good. As long as your problem is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Quaternion.Lerp()` should work fine for your needs - however, your usage of it supplies some incorrect parameters to the method, which is why it wasn't working as expected. (Also, you probably shouldn't be constructing a Quaternion using its constructor, there are helper methods to properly convert from Euler angles.)

What you need to do is record the *initial* starting and ending rotations, and pass them into `Quaternion.Lerp()` every time you call it. Note that you can't just reference `transform.rotation` every frame, because it will be changing as the object rotates. For example, adjusting your code to work:

```
Quaternion startRotation;
Quaternion endRotation;
float rotationProgress = -1;

// Call this to start the rotation
void StartRotating(float zPosition){

    // Here we cache the starting and target rotations
    startRotation = transform.rotation;
    endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, zPosition);

    // This starts the rotation, but you can use a boolean flag if it's clearer for you
    rotationProgress = 0;
}

void Update() {
    if (rotationProgress < 1 && rotationProgress >= 0){
        rotationProgress += Time.deltaTime * 5;

        // Here we assign the interpolated rotation to transform.rotation
        // It will range from startRotation (rotationProgress == 0) to endRotation (rotationProgress >= 1)
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, endRotation, rotationProgress);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I used more or less the same in my answer below, your answer is a lot more complete so I marked it correct. Thank you for the in detail help.

Comment: Thanks! It seems you were finding your own solution as I was writing up my answer - I hope it at least helped flesh out your knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else comes across this, I got mine working using the below code:

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, -30);
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(direction);
this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 1);
```