# Unity 3D Cube-Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have simple unity project where i created simple cube. When i press spacebar this cube jumps.

My Problem is - i want to implement also 360 Rotation around Y-axis (only once and then stops) when i press spacebar.  How can i do this?

Heres my current code:

```
void Start () {

        mSpeed = 3f;
        RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(mSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime,0f,mSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*Time.deltaTime);
        //transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 100 * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) 
        {
            RB.velocity = new Vector3 (0,5,0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can rotate using Slerp and Lerp functions, if you want it to be controlled by inputs you should use a co-routine if you just want consistent motion put it in the update method.  it might be better if you just researched how to make a simple game it will get all these little questions out of the way

Comment: Do you want to rotate instantly or over time?

Comment: With the `RotateObject` function from the duplicated question, do this: `StartCoroutine(RotateObject(gameObject, new Vector3(0f,360f,0f), 1f));` The  `1f` will make it rotate over one second. You can set it to `0` if you want it to rotate immediately.

Comment: @cNuts when i press the spacebar i want to rotate this cube once 360d. around y-axis and then stop the rotation. Can u help me with this ?

Comment: Since the question was mark duplicate i can't do much but have you tried what @Programmer said i haven't tested the function but i'm pretty sure it works as intended and he even told you what values you need to give it.

Comment: nope, i didnt get any error but it doesnt work

Comment: Well try putting this `transform.RotateAround (transform.position, transform.up, 360f);` in your `if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) ` It should make it rotate instantly 360 degrees.

Comment: i copy-pasted the code but when i press the spacebar the cube only jumps but doesnt rotate itself

Comment: Well you do understand that if you make an object rotate 360 degrees instantly you won't really see anything.

Comment: @CNuts how can i add time for this 360 Rotation ? for example - i want to rotate this cube around y axis in 2 seconds (360degrees)

Comment: The `RotateObject` function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651423/rotating-a-gameobject-to-a-specific-point) should work. You could edit your question with how you tried it maybe you didn't implement it right.

Comment: @CNuts I apologize to both of you. There seems to be a problem when rotation supplied is above 170 degrees. This has been fixed by removing `Quaternion`. The function now uses `Vector3` for every calculation. Please copy the new `RotateObject ` function and it should work like magic. Let me know if there is still a problem.