# Rotate GameObject around pivot point over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rotating a point in relation to another pivot point using the following code:

```
Vector3 RotatePointAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 angles) {

    Vector3 dir = point - pivot; // get point direction relative to pivot
    dir = Quaternion.Euler(angles) * dir; // rotate it
    point = dir + pivot; // calculate rotated point
    return point;
}
```

How can I rotate the point over a specific duration, say 5 seconds using a coroutine?

Comment: See the rotate function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586407/rotate-gameobject-over-time/37588536#37588536) post. Does that help?

Comment: @Programmer from the linked post the rotation is done on a game object with a transform. That makes things a lot simpler. What I am trying to do is a bit different - rotating a point based on another.

Comment: It's almost the-same. All you have to do is to add this code in your question inside that function then replace the lerp with `point` variable. Something like this: `Vector3.Lerp(currentRot, point, counter / duration);`

Comment: @Programmer what exactly does the line `gameObjectToMove.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(currentRot, newRot, counter / duration);` become?

Comment: I see you are still stuck with this. Edit your question with which object/point you are rotating around and which object you are rotating. Just add a complete code to your question and I will put an answer.

Comment: @Programmer just edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified the code from my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586407/rotate-gameobject-over-time/37588536#37588536) answer to get this effect. You can read that to understand how lerp work.

What changed and why:

**1**.Got the `beginRotation` point from the `RotatePointAroundPivot` function by passing `Vector3.zero` to the angle parameter and the current Object position outside of the `while` loop. This needs to be done once as the result will be used in the `while` loop.

```
Vector3 beginRotPoint = RotatePointAroundPivot(objPoint.transform.position, pivot, Vector3.zero);
```

This is done because lerp needs a starting point. That starting point should never changed otherwise, it break the lerp function.

**2**.Generate new angle each frame in the `while` loop. This is done by lerping from `Vector3.zero` to the target angle:

```
float t = counter / duration;
Vector3 tempAngle = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, angles, t);
```

**3**.Find the final pivot angle rotation. This is done by passing the starting point from **#1** to the first parameter, the pivot point to the second parameter and finally the current angle generated from **#2** to the third parameter.

```
Vector3 tempPivot = RotatePointAroundPivot(beginRotPoint, pivot, tempAngle);
```

**4**.Finally, assign the result from **#3** to `objPoint.transform.position` instead of `objPoint.transform.eulerAngles` because you are not only moving the object. You are also rotating it.

```
objPoint.transform.position = tempPivot;
```

---

Complete code:

Your `RotatePointAroundPivot` function:

```
Vector3 RotatePointAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 angles)
{
    Vector3 dir = point - pivot; // get point direction relative to pivot
    dir = Quaternion.Euler(angles) * dir; // rotate it
    point = dir + pivot; // calculate rotated point

    return point;
}
```

Modified [`rotateObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586407/rotate-gameobject-over-time/37588536#37588536) function that I described what changed above:

```
bool rotating = false;

IEnumerator rotateObject(GameObject objPoint, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 angles, float duration)
{
    if (rotating)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    rotating = true;

    Vector3 beginRotPoint = RotatePointAroundPivot(objPoint.transform.position, pivot, Vector3.zero);

    float counter = 0;
    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;

        float t = counter / duration;
        Vector3 tempAngle = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, angles, t);

        Vector3 tempPivot = RotatePointAroundPivot(beginRotPoint, pivot, tempAngle);
        objPoint.transform.position = tempPivot;
        Debug.Log("Running: " + t);
        yield return null;
    }
    rotating = false;
}
```

---

**USAGE**:

Will rotate object 180-deg around pivot point in 5 seconds:

```
//The GameObject with the pivot point to move
public GameObject pointToRotate;
//The Pivot point to move the GameObject around
public Transform pivotPoint;

//The angle to Move the pivot point
public Vector3 angle = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f);

//The duration for the rotation to occur
public float rotDuration = 5f;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(rotateObject(pointToRotate, pivotPoint.position, angle, rotDuration));
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the elaborate explanation. It really helps.

Comment: I have been following this question. How would I run two `rotateObject` coroutines at the same time? I tried calling one directly after the other and only the first one was run, it seems.

Comment: @SuperHyperMegaSomething Remove the `bool rotating = false;` code and any part of the code that uses it in the `rotateObject` function. This includes removing the `yield break;` code. I did that to make sure that you don't call the function twice while passing the-same object to it as that will result to multiple coroutine functions modifying one object at the-same time.