# How can I clamp Quaternion on Y?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Later also to the sides but for now on Y.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class RotationTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Transform objToRotate;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 relativePos = target.position - objToRotate.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
        rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -1f, 1f);
        objToRotate.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

I tried with the line :

```
rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -1f, 1f);
```

but it's not working I tried also the values -50f and 50f

Answer (score 1):

[`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) has **four** components, `x, y, z, w` and they all move in the range `-1, 1` .. so your clamping is absolutely useless ;)

=> **Never** touch a the components of a `Quaternion` directly unless you really know exactly what you are doing!

---

In your case you seem to want to limit the angle it rotates around the given axis (in your case Vector3.up) so what you can use would be [`Quaternion.ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html), limit that angle and convert it back to a rotation using [`Quaternion.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) like e.g.

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
// Extract the axis and angle
rotation.ToAngleAxis (out var angle, out var axis);
// Since ToAngleAxis returns only unsigned angle
// this checks if we actually have a negative rotation
if(angle > 180)
{
     angle -= 360;
}
// Clamp the angle to the desired limits
angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, -50, 50);
// Finally convert both back to a rotation
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);
```

Comment: When I move the target object behind the objToRotate the objToRotate is getting back to its original idle position but how can I make that it will return to its original idle position a bit slower smooth? If I move the target object sharp very fast behind the player's head his head returns to the original idle position but too fast. I want that his head will return slower smooth to its original pos when the target object is behind the player.

Comment: Nothing in your code is moving smooth at all. If you want smooth rotation then see e.g. [Rotate GameObject over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586407/rotate-gameobject-over-time)