# Increase and decrease light intensity overtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create some fireflies in Unity. I want to Increase light intensity then wait some seconds and then decrease it in Unity. When they get spawned, I want them increasing their light intensity, wait some seconds and then fade out. How can I create this "process" in a clean way?

```
private Light pointLight; // The light component of the firefly

private float minLuminosity = 0; // min intensity
private float maxLuminosity = 1; // max intensity

private float luminositySteps = 0.005f; // factor when increasing / decreasing

private float shineDuration = 3; // wait 3 seconds when faded in

private void Start()
{
    pointLight = GetComponent<Light>();
    pointLight.intensity = Random.Range(minLuminosity, maxLuminosity); // start with a random intensity
    StartCoroutine(ChangeIntensity()); // start the process
}

private IEnumerator ChangeIntensity()
{
    pointLight.intensity += luminositySteps; // increase the firefly intensity / fade in
    yield return new WaitWhile(() => pointLight.intensity >= maxLuminosity); // wait for the maximum intensity

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(shineDuration); // wait 3 seconds

    pointLight.intensity -= luminositySteps;
    yield return new WaitWhile(() => pointLight.intensity <= maxLuminosity); // wait for the minimum intensity

    StartCoroutine(ChangeIntensity()); // do it again
}
```

So obviously the coroutine stops forever at the first `WaitWhile()` How can I create such a code chain? When fading in or out, I just mean changing the light intensity.

Comment: What do you mean by "fade out"? You mean on the light intensity?

Comment: yes, I just want to change the light intensity

Comment: Was out doing something else. Came back and saw some answers but they  need improvement so I added mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though this has been solved, the current solutions are just decrementing the variable and also creates new object (`WaitForSeconds`) every frame.

The proper way of doing this in Unity is using `Mathf.Lerp` and `Time.deltaTime`. This type of operation is what `Mathf.Lerp` is made for which is to go from your `minLuminosity` to `maxLuminosity`. You can read more about this in my other question for fading out/in GameObject using its alpha component [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935943/3785314).

I took the `fadeInAndOut` function from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935943/3785314) and ported it to work with the `Light` component. Here is a simple light fade in/out function:

```
IEnumerator fadeInAndOut(Light lightToFade, bool fadeIn, float duration)
{
    float minLuminosity = 0; // min intensity
    float maxLuminosity = 1; // max intensity

    float counter = 0f;

    //Set Values depending on if fadeIn or fadeOut
    float a, b;

    if (fadeIn)
    {
        a = minLuminosity;
        b = maxLuminosity;
    }
    else
    {
        a = maxLuminosity;
        b = minLuminosity;
    }

    float currentIntensity = lightToFade.intensity;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;

        lightToFade.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(a, b, counter / duration);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Now, to create the exact effect you want which is to increase light intensity then wait some seconds and then decrease it, create another coroutine function that calls the function above and waits for it to finish. You can do that by yielding the `fadeInAndOut` function. Notice how `WaitForSeconds` is declared outside the `while` loop so that it does not create new Object each time.

```
//Fade in and out forever
IEnumerator fadeInAndOutRepeat(Light lightToFade, float duration, float waitTime)
{
    WaitForSeconds waitForXSec = new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    while (true)
    {
        //Fade out
        yield return fadeInAndOut(lightToFade, false, duration);

        //Wait
        yield return waitForXSec;

        //Fade-in 
        yield return fadeInAndOut(lightToFade, true, duration);
    }
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
public Light lightToFade;
public float eachFadeTime = 2f;
public float fadeWaitTime = 5f;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(fadeInAndOutRepeat(lightToFade, eachFadeTime, fadeWaitTime));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code was that you applied your luminosity change only once, thus your `WaitWhile` condition would never be reached. I would change both `WaitWhile` into simple while loops, and then use [WaitForEndOfFrame](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html):

```
private IEnumerator ChangeIntensity()
{
    while(true)
    {
        while(pointLight.intensity <= maxLuminosity)
        {
            pointLight.intensity += luminositySteps; // increase the firefly intensity / fade in
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(shineDuration); // wait 3 seconds

        while(pointLight.intensity > minLuminosity)
        {
            pointLight.intensity -= luminositySteps;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work, the Coroutine just stops there too

Comment: @peterHasemann I don't see how could that be possible. Did you put the inferior than and superior than operators correctly?

Comment: Isuka, probably the second while should be "while(pointLight.intensity > minLuminosity)", not "while(pointLight.intensity > maxLuminosity)".

Comment: I just copied your could and tried using it. The loop just stopped instantly like my old code :/

Comment: @rs232 Indeed, should have checked that.

Comment: @Isuka I tried to use your new code again, this seems to be better than mine but it does not restart the process? after decreasing it to 0, there is no new coroutine starting again

Comment: @peterHasemann Starting the same coroutine again may be avoided. Just set a while(true) loop like this, in case your firefly is staying forever on your scene.

Comment: hmm .. I used this code again, it increases to 1, waits 3 seconds, decreases to 0 and stops. I really don't get it. Thought your while loop should restart it

Comment: @peterHasemann Change the >= operator from the second if into a > one. Problem was that luminosity can't be negative, so it would stick to 0 and never leave this while loop.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it by using the following while loop

```
private IEnumerator ChangeIntensity()
{
    while (true)
    {
        pointLight.intensity += isIncreasing ? luminositySteps : -luminositySteps;

        if (pointLight.intensity <= minLuminosity)
            isIncreasing = true;

        if (pointLight.intensity >= maxLuminosity)
        {
            isIncreasing = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(shineDuration);
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```