# Trancparency in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I hope my question is not  duplicate;
I have a problem in unity.
I write a class for transparency(fade in/fade out loop) of object.that's worked right.
I put two button in scene.They are in canvas place.
after run ,Even though I have written a command for transparency one object in canvas, all the things inside go to transparency(fade in and fade out loop).
I do n't know.
please help.

myclass

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System;

public class Transparent : MonoBehaviour {

private float duration =  .7f;
    public float waitTime;
    IEnumerator co2;
    // Update is called once per frame void 
    public void start_tranparecncy()
    {
        this.co2=this.blink();
        this.StartCoroutine (this.co2);
    }
    IEnumerator blink() { 

        //Color textureColor = this.transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
        Color textureColor = this.transform.GetComponent<Image>().material.color;

        //textureColor.a = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration; 
        //this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = textureColor;
        while (true) { // this could also be a condition indicating "alive or dead"
            // we scale all axis, so they will have the same value, 
            // so we can work with a float instead of comparing vectors
            textureColor.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            this.transform.transform.GetComponent<Image> ().material.color = textureColor;

            // reset the timer

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);



        }
        //end of if(this.transform.childCount =0)

    }

    void stop_Transparency () 
    {

        this.StopCoroutine (this.co2);

    }
}
```

[image: picture of my project]

[image: picture of my project]

Comment: Please provide your code, if possible images also

Comment: It's unclear. Please use the correct naming conventions. You probably mean function instead of _command_? What is _canvas place_? You mean Screen Space - Overlay? _'all the things inside go to transparency'_ isn't that what you're trying to achieve? Transparency in Unity?

Comment: @EmreE oh i'm sorry

Comment: @MrDos yes Brother

Comment: Where did you attached this script? On canvas itself or an object which is child of the canvas ?

Comment: @EmreE  i create a ui button in scene and set a sprite as image for that.

Comment: @EmreE     I just attached this script for one button...

Comment: @EmreE    on one object that child of the canvas

Comment: I'll run your code. Right now i can only say; there is a double transform on your code `this.transform.transform.GetComponent<Image>()`.  Not sure what it suppose to do.

Comment: @EmreE    I do not know if it was inadvertently wrong, I corrected the code, but it is still a problem..

Comment: Not exactly sure what your problem is but this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933517/fading-in-out-gameobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found you problem it is mainly of

```c#
this.transform.transform.GetComponent<Image>();
```

Because of double transform, it reaches one upper level to parent which is your canvas itself. So everything in your canvas looses alpha value.

Also edited your code a bit. Instead of using materials color, directly changed Image Component's color value of alpha.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System;

public class Transparent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float duration = .7f;
    public float waitTime;
    IEnumerator co2;

    public void start_tranparecncy()
    {
        this.co2 = this.blink();
        this.StartCoroutine(this.co2);
    }

    IEnumerator blink()
    {
        //Color textureColor = this.transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
        Color textureColor = this.transform.GetComponent<Image>().color;

        //textureColor.a = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration; 
        //this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = textureColor;

        while (true)
        { // this could also be a condition indicating "alive or dead"
            // we scale all axis, so they will have the same value, 
            // so we can work with a float instead of comparing vectors
            textureColor.a = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration;
            this.transform.GetComponent<Image>().color = textureColor;

            // reset the timer

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);  
        }
        //end of if(this.transform.childCount =0)

    }

    void stop_Transparency()
    {   
        this.StopCoroutine(this.co2); 
    }
}
```

I've attached this script to a button in canvas. Also run the `start_tranparecncy()` function in the same button's `On Click()`.

After pressing the button, only the button's alpha value is changing.

You can change the `On Click()` and add on another button if you like.

Comment: my friend i need to run fade in/fade out in start scene...i run start_transparency method with script.......for eg :throw_text_p1.gameObject.GetComponent<Transparent> ().start_tranparecncy (); command .