# Use MoveTowards with duration instead of speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lerp

I want to move **GameObject** from position A to B with [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) within x seconds and in a coroutine function. I know how to do this with [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) but this time would prefer to do it with `Vector3.MoveTowards` since both functions behave differently.

With `Vector3.Lerp`, this is done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850253/move-gameobject-over-time/36851965#36851965):

```
IEnumerator moveToX(Transform fromPosition, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;

    //Get the current position of the object to be moved
    Vector3 startPos = fromPosition.position;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        fromPosition.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I tried to do the the-same thing with `Vector3.MoveTowards`, but it's not working properly. The problem is that the move finishes before the x time or duration. Also, it doesn't move smoothly. It jumps to the middle of both positions than to the end of position B.

This is the function that uses `Vector3.MoveTowards` with the issue above:

```
IEnumerator MoveTowards(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;
        float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / duration;

        objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition,
         time);

        Debug.Log(counter + " / " + duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

How do you move GameObject from position A to B with [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) within x seconds and in a coroutine function?

Please do not suggest `Vector3.Lerp` as that's not what I want to use.

**EDIT**:

Replacing

```
float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / duration;
```

with

```
float time = Vector3.Distance(startPos, toPosition) / (duration * 60f);
```

works but introduces a problem when focus is shifted from Unity to another application. Doing that causes the movement to not finish. Calculating it every frame instead of once before starting the timer seems more reasonable.

MatrixTai's answer fixed both problems.

Comment: Can you make a try that, change `float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / duration;` to `float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration-counter);`, as I dun have unity right now, so I am not sure my guessing is correct.

Comment: @MatrixTai Just did. It went even faster and finished before the time.

Comment: Oops, sorry forget to add * deltatime, the one I want to try should be `float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration-counter) * Time.deltaTime;`

Comment: That worked. See my edit for another alternative I came up with but what's in your comment is more reliable. You should create an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I have long time not touching Unity... but I do believe you mess up in the calculation.

First of all, `Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition, time)` is talking about

> Walking from `currentPos` to `toPosition` with each frame moving
>   certain distance `time`.

Thus using `time` as name is confusing, but fine lets keep it.

However, you will notice in the statement, `time` is something move each frame. But `Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / duration` is velocity (m/s), not (m/frame). To make it (m/frame), simply times `Time.deltatime` which is (s/frame).

Secondly,

When in coroutine, which means the function is iterated each frame. In the line `float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / duration * Time.deltatime;`, what you will notice is that the `time` keeps on decreasing when going next frame as distance become smaller and smaller.

To be more concrete, we can do some math. Typically this should be done with calculus, but lets simplify it by considering just 2 points. When object postion d = 0, and object postion d ~= 9.9, assume endpoint at 10.

At point 1, the object has `time` = (10-0)/duration, full speed.
At point 2, the object has `time` = (10-9.9)/duration, 1/10 of full speed.

Unless you want it to move slower every frame, you cannot hold the value of duration unchanged. As after each frame, you want the velocity to be kept, duration should thus decreases with distance.

To make that physics work, minus the duration for the time passed.

So the final solution is

```
float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration-counter) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Here is the complete function:

```
IEnumerator MoveTowards(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

        float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

        objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition, time);

        Debug.Log(counter + " / " + duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```